# How can I load image from Picasso to androidStudio project?

Tags: java, android, picasso, openweathermap

I develop to weather application with "OpenWeatherMap" API. I can write to load image command from this API but can't load weather icon to ImageView as "ImageWeat".

```
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
                JSONObject object3 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                String img = object3.getString("icon");
                Picasso.get().load("https://openweathermap.org/img/wn"+img+"@2x.png").into(imageWeat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following library to view or set image using Picasso
Add in your gradle file.

```
implementation ‘com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2’
```

And Access it using:

```
 Picasso.with(this)
            .load("imageurl")
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .centerCrop()
            .fit()
            .into(imageView);
```